# How to set hostname with cloud-init and Terraform?

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

I am starting with Terraform. I am trying to make it set a friendly hostname, instead of the usual `ip-10.10.10.10` that AWS uses. However, I haven't found how to do it.

I tried using provisioners, like this:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "sudo hostnamectl set-hostname friendly.example.com"
}
```

But that doesn't work, the hostname is not changed.

So now, I'm trying this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-XXXXXXXX"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags = {
    Name    = "friendly.example.com"
  }
  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
}

data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("user-data.conf")}"
  vars {
    hostname = "${aws_instance.example.tags.Name}"
  }
}
```

And in `user-data.conf` I have a line to use the variable, like so:

```
hostname = ${hostname}
```

But this gives me a cycle dependency:

```
$ terraform apply
Error: Error asking for user input: 1 error(s) occurred:
* Cycle: aws_instance.example, data.template_file.user_data
```

Plus, that would mean I have to create a different `user_data` resource for each instance, which seems a bit like a pain. Can you not reuse them? That should be the purpose of templates, right?

I must be missing something, but I can't find the answer.
Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the first attempt: `local-exec` executes on your "local" device. You want `remote-exec`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard ah, thanks! I thought it was local to the instance being provisioned. I will try this.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I got it working, thanks to your suggestion. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as chosen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a Terraform `provisioner` with the `local-exec` block will execute it on the device from which Terraform is applying: [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html). Note specifically the line:

> This invokes a process on the machine running Terraform, not on the resource. See the remote-exec provisioner to run commands on the resource.

Therefore, switching the `provisioner` from a `local-exec` to a `remote-exec`:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = ["sudo hostnamectl set-hostname friendly.example.com"]
}
```

should fix your issue with setting the hostname.

Comment: the `remote-exec` provisioner uses `inline` and not `command`. Also make sure inline is an array of commands; `inline = ['sudo hostnamectl set-hostname friendly.example.com']`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are supplying the tag to the instance as a string, why not just make that a var?

Replace the string `friendly.example.com` with `${var.instance-name}` in your instance resource and in your data template. Then set the var:

```
variable "instance-name" {
    default="friendly.example.com"
}
```

Comment: ok, that solves the cycle problem, and gets the correct hostname, yay!
However, if I now add a second instance, I need to create a different variable, and a different user_data template, right? That doesn't seem very flexible.

Comment: Lookup use count and then count.index to iterate through multiple instances. Also use aws_launch-configs not aws_instance

Comment: This would be a better answer if it was a more complete example showing how to refer to the variable/local and was properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your `user-data.conf` should be bash script, to start with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

It should look like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
hostname ${hostname}
```

Comment: When/if the instance gets rebooted the hostname get reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here in case it helps someone

If you want to set the hostname to the `Instance ID` then you can now do this directly in Terraform using the [private_dns_name_options resource block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#private-dns-name-options) that was released in [AWS Provider v4.20.0 or above](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/25139), without having to mess with cloudinit or user-data

*Note:* If your server already exists and is running you might have to reboot or possibly recreate it with these new options. Also `resource-name` is actually the `Instance ID` and not the `Instance Name` as the variable name suggests unfortunately

```
resource "aws_instance" "server" {
...

  private_dns_name_options {
    hostname_type = "resource-name"
  }
}
```